# Question mark in Address Bar?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

Pretend there's a website.
**http://example.com/donate**
Then you click a link and bam it turns into
**http://example.com/donate?id=1**
How would I get the **?id=1** in my webpages like that?
What I want to do is have a user click on a link in a page, and have another page show up while on the same exact URL, and I would like it to show like a **?id=1** or something along those lines. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `$_GET['id']` your welcome

Comment: Are you learning PHP from a tutorial? Doesn't it have a section explaining how PHP scripts get URL parameters? This is such a basic question, it seems like you haven't tried to learn.

Answer (score 1):

see [Variables From External Sources](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) in the PHP manual.

The part after the ? is called [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). And the name=value pairs (like e.g. id=1) are the parameters of a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You set that information in the HTML like

```
<a href="example.com/donate?id=1">Click Me</a>
```

When that script runs you see what `id` was set to by quizzing the `$_GET` array like so

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_GET['id'] ) {

        // do something with it
    }
```